# unable to install sublime text 3

Tags: installation, sublimetext

showing this error while installing sublime text on Ubuntu 16.04.

[image: **enter image description here**]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you checkout [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for future endeavor at Stack overflow.Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community  -Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You have missed a space before the url. Use this exact command:

`wget -qO - https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -`